# Using Stagemonitor/Hyperic HQ to monitor client specific performance stats in a multi tenancy environment

Tags: java, mysql, performance, multi-tenant, stagemonitor

Using a multi-tenant server is it possible to use these tools to get stats regarding specific clients performance usage. The setup would be a MySQL DB which holds users belonging to organisations. When the Java application is running all actions will be carried out by a User collection which has the Organisation ID variable.

Could this data then be used to work out how much CPU, memory, heap, processes etc are being used per Organisation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not provide anything more than how much data each tenant has.  That can be found in `information_schema`.

If you need CPU/IO/etc., you need to set up multiple instances of MySQL in VMs or cgroups and have the OS / VM-manager provide the data.  This will cost extra RAM, so it may not be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is this still true given that the organisation data for each user will be available from the JVM when the application is running per session?

Comment: If the JVM can provide the data (and I don't know), the it would be up to you to record it somewhere.  Are you ready for that hassle?

Comment: I would have to be hassled to unfortunately. Whether its possible to see what user utilised particular memory etc is what I need to understand.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  I think a newer version has some per-user stats, perhaps only for memory.